# Prevent overwriting of files when using Scp

Tags: linux, scp

I was copying some files using scp and i don't want to overwrite the already present  files.

If i was using cp command, i think this can be done using cp -n.

Is there a similar option for scp, i went through the documentation of SCP and there seems to be no such option.

Is rsync or sftp the way to go solve this problem?

Addition Info:

OS: Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: [scp-without-replacing-existing-files-in-the-destination](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14191/scp-without-replacing-existing-files-in-the-destination), [how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories), [copy from remote gist](https://gist.github.com/ppdouble/273dcfd7409dab2fb7739d4def6598fa)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`rsync` seems to be the solution to your problem. Here's an example I got from [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync):

```
rsync -avz foo:src/bar /data/tmp
```

The -a option will preserve permissions, directory structure, ownership, and symlinks. You can also specify any of those options individually as well.

-v and -z mean verbose and compress respectively. You don't really need them although -z is nice if you are copying large files.

Answer (score 21):

I just found a simple hack. Mark the existing files as read-only.

Comment: That makes perfect sense if you don't want to overwrite existing files: `chmod u-w srcfile; scp -p srcfile $USER@$host:$directory/`. From the scp man page: `-p  Preserves modification times, access times, and modes from the original file.`

Comment: You could improve this answer by adding a code snippet

Answer (score 16):

```
rsync -avz --ignore-existing /source folder/* user@remoteserver:/dstfolder/
```

`--ignore-existing` will not overwrite the files on remote server or destination server*.

Answer (score 0):

I did not test it but maybe first mountung via `sshfs` and then using `cp` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I've used rsync in the past for this, but found myself trying to grab from a windows box with CopSSH and no rsync :-(  The following worked just fine for me, using file tests to eliminate the files that would be overwritten, and generating mutiple 'get' requests to an sftp instance.

```
(  echo  'cd work/ftp/' ; 
   ssh <user>@<machine> 'cd work/ftp/ && ls -1 ITEM_SALE_SUMMARY_V.*.dat.xz' |
   while read line; do [[ -f "$line" ]] || echo get "$line"; done 
) | sftp  <user>@<machine>
```

Just in case others need a non-rsync solution!

Answer (score 0):

Just to supplement the other solutions:

For one ascii/bin file, you can do it with:

`cat source_file | ssh host "test ! -f target_file && cat > target_file"`

Answer (score -3):

[rsync over ssh](https://www.google.com/search?q=rsync%20over%20ssh) it will have to be.